# wordpress err_connection_reset in Chrome from specific country

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, http, internet-explorer

I volunteer supporting a news website in Russia, which was hand-crafted in PHP back in 2002-2004. Needless to say, I was super excited when editors hired some folks to build a new version, based on WordPress.
The old site is running on **mydomain.press**. I put the new WordPress version, which is meant to replace the old one, on **subdomain.mydomain.press**.

And there's a mysterious problem with it.

When an editor is trying to access the site at **subdomain.mydomain.press**, her browser (Chrome in Russia) instantly reports **err_connection_reset**, in 9 cases out of 10. Not spinning trying to load the site - an instant error is reported.
On my machine (Canada) the same website opens no problem. Well, a little slow (hence I mentioned she's not even seeing the delay - the error is instant), but it opens in 10 out of 10 trials.
When her Chrome gets the content (in that 1/10 case), it also shows a slight delay. Only the error case is instantaneous. The old site at **mydomain.press** is opening 100% of the time.

Connecting remotely to her Windows machine (I'm using Mac OS X) via TeamViewer, I did observe the behaviour described when using **Chrome**. Interestingly enough, **IE** didn't show this problem - it loads consistently, except that once in ~10 reloads the page loads with a garbled styling. As if some css isn't loaded properly (but not in a way that would make it an invalid document, obviously).

I'm completely out of my depth. I tried disabling her Windows Defender to see if it's the culprit - nope. I've tried to reset her IP address (as suggested by the same page which offered the earlier way to try and fix the err_connection_reset) - no dice.

I'm not seeing either error from my own Chrome, nor the garbled css (though I didn't try with IExplorer from Canada).

I know they had some ISPs in Russia block them (silly political reason, AFAIK) in the past - but this doesn't look like blocking; she'd be 100% unable to view it otherwise. She's not under any firewall (nor is the website).

what else... nginx is the server used, the setup is "basic", I suppose (I'm not that proficient in configuring it to try anything fancy).

And to make things even more mysterious - the website at mydomain.press (the old version, php-hand-crafted) is opening just fine, 100% of trials.

Opening using the IP-address doesn't change the picture, so doesn't look like a DNS issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would try using the actual IP address of subdomain.mydomain.press to see if the problem is related to DNS lookup.

Comment: Thanks @magenta, I suppose there's a merit to this idea. Didn't think of it myself, anyway - and given that I'm completely lost with it, any suspicions should be tested... that said, I am wondering, how would it be possible that 9/10 DNS lookups fail, while 1 succeeds (and all DNS lookups succeed for mydomain.press).

Comment: The DNS server is not fixed if the first one does not respond in good time it will fallback to a secondary server. You DNS server is probably not the same given your location and hers are very different.

Comment: that's another good point!

Comment: You have edited your question and I see you have changed  mydinain.press to mydomain.press. So, I think subdomain.mydomain.press and mydomain.press are probably sharing the same ip address. In this case the hosts are differentiated by the HTTP host header field which means you cannot access the site with an ip address alone. However, you can verify that DNS is correctly returning the right ip address by using the tool nslookup.

Comment: Note that a DNS server has an entry for both mydomain.press and subdomain.mydomain.press even though they both have the same value.

Comment: No, they are different droplets (Digital Ocean machines) with different IP addresses. I know that for sure. It was just me correcting a typo.

Comment: What do you use on server side Apache or nginx? Do you see the access log when connection reset is there? You should be debugging server as well not just looking at what is happening at client side. Also would suggest to enable https, in case it is not already enabled

Comment: @Tarun - nginx, and my chief suspicion now is that it's misconfigured... No the access log has no mention of the failed connections.

Comment: Have you asked her to check that site with proxy server or you try to check with Rusian ip?

Comment: @dipmala - she does say that the site is opening fine when she's under TOR. Now I'm working on turning SSL for the thing...

Comment: try to call it with a proxy from russia and debug it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing battle of Roskomnadzor against Telegram messenger in Russia, which affects subnets, DNS and DPI hardware around the country. Try to connect via proxy or VPN server outside Russia and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: the original site, hand-coded by the heroes of old, back when ships were made of wood and men made of iron, is working fine.. plus, whatever RosKomNadzor is doing, it would likely be blocking on a DNS level (and we do have that problem with some providers) - but this issue appears when the IP is used too. It got to be server configuration.